# Using node express with node versions 10 and above fails

Tags: node.js, express

I can see many posts on this problem, but no one answers the simple question.
I want to type

express myNewProject

on a system running node V12.16.2

All the replies get into WHY it fails, such as "fs.writeFile(...) requires a third (or fourth) parameter"

Am I really forced to not use express any more?  Is there some fix I can apply to my system and make this work?

here is the session:

bcuser@autumn14:~$ express myNewProject

create : myNewProject

install dependencies:
     $ cd myNewProject && npm install

run the app:
     $ DEBUG=myNewProject ./bin/www

fs.js:144
  throw new ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK(cb);
  ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received { mode: 438 }
    at maybeCallback (fs.js:144:9)
    at Object.writeFile (fs.js:1252:14)
    at write (/usr/lib/node_modules/express-generator/bin/express:246:6)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/express-generator/bin/express:210:5
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/express-generator/bin/express:261:11
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/express-generator/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:29:20
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:155:23) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK'
}

Comment: There's nothing we can directly help with here.  There's no code.  There's no precise error message and a precise line of code that the error occurs on.  There's no evidence you did any debugging on your own to see what exact code was causing the problem, etc..  Express is working just fine for me with node v12.13.1.  We aren't sure how to help without more info.

Comment: Sorry, I thought this was a well known problem.  I edited the original post with the complete session.  This works fine if node is V9 or earlier, but not V10 on breaks.

Comment: Have you updated Express and express generator to current versions?

Comment: running express 4.9.0

Comment: is there a separate install for express generator? Thought it was one thing

Comment: Well, the current version is 4.17.1.  You can either look back in the Express version history to see when this issue was fixed.  Starting in node v10, a callback was required for more `fs` functions than previously.

Comment: It looks to me like `express-generator` is it's own package [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-generator).  I use Express, but not express-generator and don't seem to have the generator installed so it appears to be a separate install to me.

Comment: Ok, thanks all , I'll figure out how to get to 4.17.1

Comment: There is plenty of discussion of this type of problem in express-generator.  Looks like you  need an update at least for that.  Also won't hurt to upgrade Express to the latest version too.

Answer (score 0):

This error looks like you need to update either express or express-generator to the latest version.  You're on Express 4.9.0 and the latest is 4.17.1.  The error stack looks like it's referring to express-generator, but perhaps it's a version of Express embedded into the express-generator install.  In either case, I think you need a newer version.

As for background, starting in node.js v10, node started requiring asynchronous callbacks on a number of asynchronous functions such as `fs.write()` and `fs.unlink()`.  So, any code that was kind of doing fire and forget calling of those functions without paying any attention to the completion or error (by not providing a callback function) would generate this `ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK` error.